# Result for Age in Days JS challenget problem?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm following Clever Programmer's youtube JS tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qqx_wzMmFeA&ab_channel=CleverProgrammer), and the first challenge is an Age in Days calculator with two buttons and a results box.

The only problem is when I click the 'Click me' button, it does NOT correctly display the answer (which should print 'You are XXXX days old'), but instead displays the JS code in full (i.e the function and all my comments, but not the actual answer).

I have checked each file (HTML, CSS and JS) and I cannot find where the error is or what is causing it?

I believe it is something to do with these lines of code in the JS function:

```
h1.appendChild(textAnswer); 
document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
```

The full code is here and I will attach an image of the problem (how it displays the answer).

```js
function ageInDays() {
  var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born... Good friend?');
  var ageInDayss = (2020 - birthYear) * 365;
  var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
  var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDays + ' days old');
  h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
  h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
  document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
}
```

```css
.container-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-box-container-1 {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-box-container-1">
      <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result currently:

[image]

Comment: You are using the wrong variable. `document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDays + ' days old');`. You are using the function name as the variable here. This is why you should follow better standards when naming variables. You defined the age number as `ageInDayss`.

Comment: As @RRK says:
In `function ageInDays()`, use the variable:
`var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are ' + ageInDayss + ' days old');`.